# JQuery behaves strange with different IE8 security settings

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Good day!

I'm not sure if I hit the bug, so please confirm that I'm not mad. I use IE 8.0.7600.16385 on 3 different machines.

Here is simple page (I tested with both JQuery 1.4.2 and 1.3.2). It just displays alert if hidden link is visible. It displays 'false' in all browsers I have and in my IE8 when security zone is set to 'Trusted intranet' or it in IE7 compatibility mode. But when I upload this page (or change security zone to 'Internet') -- it displays 'true'.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="ru">
<head>
    <title>     
    </title>       
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />       
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script> 
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#vct-save-settings').click(function(){
            alert('Is visible hidden element: ' + $('#vct-show-similar').is(':visible'));           
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="vct-controls">
    <a href="#" id="vct-hide-similar">Shown element</a>
    <a href="#" id="vct-show-similar" style="display: none;">Hidden element</a>
    <a href="#" id="vct-save-settings">click me!</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

So, the question is: why JQuery behaves different regardless of IE8 security zones?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd log a bug.  That's definitely incorrect behavior.

Comment: It appears to be happening because IE is reporting that the width and height of the element are non-zero, and the jQuery filter routine thinks that's more important than "display: none".  (Yes, that's a bug.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already logged in the jQuery bug tracker (bug 6199).

*edit* — also it just occurred to me that this might be a security thing related to the trick of putting a `<a>` tag on a page and having a ":visited" style for it, and then checking its current style via Javascript. That way, a page can tell what *other* sites you have visited. I don't know why this behavior in particular should result, but that's the only reason I can imagine that the security zone would figure into the behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, it seems the security zones also affect on other JQuery functionality -- for example sorting from JQuery UI etc. It seems some restrictions are applied to Javascript. May be you have any details on it?

It seems very-very frustrating to have browser behave fundamentally different with default settings...

Comment: Link to the bug-report page: http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/6199

It seems you haven't mentioned that it behaves differently on different security zones...

Comment: No the bug report doesn't mention that - I'll add a comment.  Actually this is the first time I've ever heard of such weird behavior from IE8.  I've seen other strange things, but nothing like this, with differences in different security zones.

Comment: Can I ask you to check you your demo by adding your link (http://gutfullofbeer.net/visible.html) to local intranet zone temporary in your IE8. If I'm not mad it should work. Thanks!

Comment: OOps - I had commented that I could not make IE report "false", but I had just done it wrong - so yes, I agree with you - it behaves exactly as you say!

Comment: Also it seems to happen for tags other than `<a>`; I changed the test to use a `<span>` tag and it behaves exactly the same way.

Comment: IE8 reports 'false' when 

a) I delete the first link (before hidden)

or 

b) Turn on IE7 compatibility:

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />

Comment: OK, well I think that bottom line for the jQuery code is that it needs to trust the reported height/width less than the current CSS style. I'm sure they don't go for the style right away because it's probably more expensive than checking height/width.

Comment: A quick fix would be to have the return statement for jQuery's `hidden` filter check if it has IE with `elem.currentStyle` in the return statement. As in `width > 0 && height > 0 && !skip && !elem.currentStyle ?`

Comment: I'm afraid that IE security zones have more bugs... (I have hit at least two, but I didn't have test cases yet)